Closing Errant Solana Token Accounts
I've mistakenly minted more than one iteration of a token using MetaPlex's createAndMint method by running the program four times. My goal is to close three of the token accounts, returning the SOL used for rent, and leaving only one as the official token.
I've put together this function to that end:
import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey, Transaction, sendAndConfirmTransaction } from "@solana/web3.js";
import * as fs from "fs";

async function closeTokenAccount() {
  // Set up connection
  const connection = new Connection(process.env.MY_QUICKNODE_CONN_STR);

  // Load your wallet keypair
  const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("guideSecret.json", "utf8")));
  const payer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);

  // Replace with the specific token account public key you want to close
  const tokenAccountPubkey = new PublicKey(process.env.TOKEN_ACCT_PUBKEY);

  try {
    // Check if the token account exists
    const tokenAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(tokenAccountPubkey);

    if (!tokenAccountInfo) {
      throw new Error("Token account not found");
    }

    console.log("Token Account Info:", tokenAccountInfo);

    // Close the token account
    const transaction = new Transaction().add({
      keys: [
        { pubkey: tokenAccountPubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
        { pubkey: payer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: false },
      ],
      programId: new PublicKey(process.env.CUSTOM_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),
      data: Buffer.alloc(0), // CloseAccount instruction has no data
    });

    // Sign and send the transaction
    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [payer], // Signing payer's keypair
      { commitment: "confirmed" } // Ensure transaction is confirmed
    );

    console.log("Token account closed:", signature);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error closing token account:", error);
  }
}

closeTokenAccount().catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

However, when the program is run, it produces the following error:
Error closing token account: SendTransactionError: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xc. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program <CUSTOM_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID> invoke [1]",
  "Program log: Error: Invalid instruction",
  "Program <CUSTOM_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID> consumed 686 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program <CUSTOM_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID> failed: custom program error: 0xc"
]. 

All of the environment variables have been quadruple-checked for correctness, so it's not an issue of passing incorrect values. The connection endpoint is up and running with no issues, also.
Can this method be fixed to properly close and refund these accounts, or is there some other method I could try?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
